# Can't connect to HTTPS websites via squid proxy

Tags: squid, centos7

I've just tried to create a proxy server on a OpenVZ VPS in CentOS7.
All good, but I can't access https websites like google, instagram, facebook, etc..it says timeout, took too long to respond.

I've generated a myCA.pem certificate and using ssl_bump I've linked the signed certificate without errors (checked with `systemctl status squid`) and now all when I'm trying to connect to the websites above enumerated it gives me no internet error:

[image: 1]

Below is my `squid.conf` and here my `cache.log` http://pastebin.com/MUkujTig

```
acl localhost src 127.0.0.1/32
acl to_localhost dst 127.0.0.0/8 0.0.0.0/32
acl SSL_ports port 443
acl Safe_ports port 80        # http
acl Safe_ports port 21        # ftp
acl Safe_ports port 443        # https
acl Safe_ports port 1025-65535    # unregistered ports
acl Safe_ports port 280        # http-mgmt
acl Safe_ports port 488        # gss-http
acl Safe_ports port 591        # filemaker
acl Safe_ports port 777        # multiling http
acl CONNECT method CONNECT

http_access allow manager localhost
http_access deny manager
http_access deny !Safe_ports
http_access deny CONNECT !SSL_ports
http_access allow all
http_port 3128 ssl-bump \
 generate-host-certificates=on \
 dynamic_cert_mem_cache_size=4MB \
 key=/etc/squid/ssl_cert/myCA.pem \
 cert=/etc/squid/ssl_cert/myCA.pem

# SSL Bump Config
always_direct allow all
ssl_bump server-first all
sslproxy_cert_error deny all
sslproxy_flags DONT_VERIFY_PEER
sslcrtd_program /usr/lib64/squid/ssl_crtd -s /var/lib/ssl_db -M 4MB    sslcrtd_children 8 startup=1 idle=1

hierarchy_stoplist cgi-bin ?
coredump_dir /var/spool/squid
cache deny all

refresh_pattern ^ftp:        1440    20%    10080
refresh_pattern ^gopher:    1440    0%    1440
refresh_pattern -i (/cgi-bin/|\?) 0    0%    0
refresh_pattern .        0    20%    4320

icp_port 3130

forwarded_for off

request_header_access Allow allow all
request_header_access Authorization allow all
request_header_access Proxy-Authorization allow all
request_header_access Proxy-Authenticate allow all
request_header_access Cache-Control allow all
request_header_access Content-Encoding allow all
request_header_access Content-Length allow all
```

I've added 3128 port in public zone using `firewall-cmd`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For my purpose it doesn't need to use sslbump so I have deleted it and solved it by adding this line in squid.conf
`dns_v4_first on`

Answer (score 3):

You log has the following line:

```
 (ssl_crtd): Failed to initialize /var/lib/ssl_db/index.txt file for writing
```

Which means that you got mistakes in your sslbump configuration.

The problem with your configuration is that you can't have `/var/lib/ssl_db` as your sslbump storage, since you won't be able to initialize it with a following command `/usr/lib64/squid/ssl_crtd -c -s /var/lib/ssl_db`. The `ssl_db` dir shoudn't exist before you issue the command or it will fail. But `squid` user can't create the directory in `/var/lib` because of permissions. So you need to change that directory to `/var/lib/squid/ssl_db` by doing the following commands (start as as root!):

1. `sudo su` (or any other mean to get root shell)
2. `mkdir /var/lib/squid/`
3. `chown -R squid:squid /var/lib/squid/`
4. `su -l squid -s /bin/bash` (next command should be run as `squid` user, so this step is important)
5. `/usr/lib64/squid/ssl_crtd -c -s /var/lib/squid/ssl_db`

If you are successful, the output should display:

```
 Initialization SSL db...
 Done
```

Now you change your squid.conf to the new ssl_db directory:

```
sslcrtd_program /usr/lib64/squid/ssl_crtd -s /var/lib/squid/ssl_db -M 4MB
```

And this directive should go from a new line, you got a mistake in your config file:

```
sslcrtd_children 8 startup=1 idle=1
```

I hope this will help (unless you are doing some censorship, then I hope it won't :))!

P.S. This is not your case, but I'll add nevertheless:

Different distros place `ssl_crtd` command into different directories, but people got a tendency to copy config files without checking its existence first. Launching `/usr/lib64/squid/ssl_crtd` as `squid` user should display:

```
Uninitialized SSL certificate database directory: . To initialize, run "ssl_crtd -c -s ".
```

If it says that `command not found`, then `ssl_crtd` might be actually located in `/usr/libexec/squid/ssl_crtd`

P.P.S. After a two-hour skype session trying to fix the unfixable the solution was found - disabling ipv6, incorrectly configured by the hosting provider :)

Who would have thought, that it all will breakdown to the following commands:

```
 sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6=1
 sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6=1
 sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6=1
```

And adding:

```
 dns_v4_first on
```

into squid.conf

Comment: Hi, I've done the changes and now the config looks like this http://i.prntscr.com/5c3c520d074c413b8e580f87a61897a3.png , but same error in cache.log with the same /var/lib/ssl_db/index.txt file for writing , I don't know why still trying to acces this folder if i've changed in the config, i've restarted squid with no errors..what am I doing wrong? I am not doing censorship or something complicated, I am just trying to create simple proxy server for using them with instagram, twitter, facebook :D not for complicated things

Comment: Can't see your screenshot, getting "access denied". If you are sure you replaced `/var/lib/ssl_db ` with `/var/lib/squid/ssl_db` everywhere in you config, try to "cheat" that stupid squid (mitmproxy works so much better :)) by moving `/var/lib/squid/ssl_db` (created with that command I gave you) to `/var/lib/ssl_db` while retaining the `squid` user ownership

Comment: `sslcrtd_program /usr/lib64/squid/ssl_crtd -s /var/lib/squid/ssl_db -M 4MB`

Comment: I assume that your squid.conf is ok. Now check all other .conf files in `/etc/squid/` directory. Or just move the folder where it wants it (and make sure to do `chown -R squid:squid /var/lib/ssl_db` after moving)

Comment: Oh, we got chat here somewhere, much better than skype :)

Comment: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46414/trying-to-help-alex-lucaci-with-his-squid

Comment: Worked for CentOS7 and squid-4.7 (uses security_file_certgen instead of ssl_crtd) too: 

# sudo rm -rf /var/spool/squid/ssl_db
# chown -R squid:squid /var/spool/squid
# su -l squid -s /bin/bash
-bash-4.2$ /usr/lib64/squid/security_file_certgen -c -s /var/spool/squid/ssl_db -M 4MB
Initialization SSL db...
Done